# How to select a link in a UL>LI and make it NOT clickable with jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I'm a bit of a nOOb with jQuery but I know it can do the following:

Select the link in the following HTML and make it not not go anywhere. (I'm doing this so it shows a dropdown instead)

Here is the HTML

```
<ul id="navigation">
  <li class="has-drop"><a href="http://72.10.55.131/shop.html/">shop</a></li>
  <li class="has-drop"><a href="http://72.10.55.131/collections.html/">collections</a></li>
</ul>
```

I'm trying to target the second one on the list. Those links are live if you want to see the source code.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: check my answer for second li only.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Capture the click event and prevent the default behavior:

```
$('#navigation li.dropdown').on('click', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: Awesome. How would I only target the second LI? That is the one I am after. The "collections.html" one. Thanks

Comment: I would give it a class. It isn't good practice to rely on the order of elements.

Comment: Agreed but I can't give it a class it is being spit out by Magento CMS.

Comment: @Mark Mitchell Just do `$('has-drop:eq(1)')` for now.

Answer (score 0):

Since you mentioned `I'm trying to target the second one on the list.` in your question, so if you only want to disable the link behavior of the second list item only then you can use

```
$('ul#navigation li').eq(1).find('a').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Otherwise (for all links) you can use `Blender`'s answer.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Xm8ay/1/).

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$('li.has-drop:eq(1) a').attr('href','#');
```